# PHP sort multidimensional array with primary & secondary keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

How do you sort a multidimensional array by primary and secondary key?
For example, assuming the following array:

```
$result = array();

$result[0]["prio"] = 1;
$result[0]["date"] = '2010-02-28';
$result[0]["post"] = "February's thoughts";

$result[1]["prio"] = 0;
$result[1]["date"] = '2010-04-20';
$result[1]["post"] = "April's thoughts";

$result[2]["prio"] = 0;
$result[2]["date"] = '2010-05-30';
$result[2]["post"] = "May's thoughts";
```

I wish to sort the column 'prio' as the **primary key (ascending)** and 'date' as the **secondary key (descending)**, to obtain:

```
$result[0]["prio"] = 0;
$result[0]["date"] = '2010-05-30';
$result[0]["post"] = "May's thoughts";
$result[1]["prio"] = 0;
$result[1]["date"] = '2010-04-20';
$result[1]["post"] = "April's thoughts";
$result[2]["prio"] = 1;
$result[2]["date"] = '2010-02-28';
$result[2]["post"] = "February's thoughts";
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Does this data originate from a database? Perhaps you could retrieve the data in correct order by modifying your original query.

Comment: Not enough data from DB to achieve this :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use usort like this:

```
$result = array();

$result[0]["prio"] = 1;
$result[0]["date"] = '2010-02-28';
$result[0]["post"] = "February's thoughts";

$result[1]["prio"] = 0;
$result[1]["date"] = '2010-04-20';
$result[1]["post"] = "April's thoughts";

$result[2]["prio"] = 0;
$result[2]["date"] = '2010-05-30';
$result[2]["post"] = "May's thoughts";

function fct($a ,$b) {

  if ($a['prio'] < $b['prio']) {
    return -1;
  } elseif  ($a['prio'] > $b['prio']) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return strcmp($b['date'], $a['date']);
  }

}

usort($result, "fct");
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [prio] => 0
            [date] => 2010-05-30
            [post] => May's thoughts
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [prio] => 0
            [date] => 2010-04-20
            [post] => April's thoughts
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [prio] => 1
            [date] => 2010-02-28
            [post] => February's thoughts
        )

)
```

Comment: Yes it will, because it compares dates when 'prio' are equal.

Answer (score 3):

[array_multisort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) should give you the functionality that you need... use Example #3 from the PHP documentation as the basis for your sort, although you'll need to convert those date strings to a datestamp value before executing the sort.

If this data has come from a database query though, it's far easier to sort it within the sql query used to retrieve the information.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't have a built-in function to do complex sorting like this, so you'll need to do a [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/usort), which allows you to sort items using a function that specifies your own criteria.

[The example given on the PHP manual page](http://ww.php.net/usort) is almost an exact match for what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Riccardo: usort allows you to specify any criteria to sort by; you can use it to sort on any one or more nested array elements. All you have to do is write a function that returns less than zero or greater than zero depending on which of any of two given elements in your array that you want sorted higher. You can sort on as many 'columns' as you like; you just have to code the function to do it. See @M42's example for proof.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `usort()` to define custom sort function.
Here's an example

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
?>
```

The output will be

```
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
3: 5
4: 6
```

More info can be found at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php
It should help you get started.